# Cloudformation Network creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I have some templates that are successfully creating various VPC resources, including two route tables, one pointing to the NAT and one to the IGW.

But a third route table, marked 'Main' is also being created.  It's being assigned to all the subnets I create.

Any clues as to why this behavior is happening?

Answer (score 2):

From [Managing route tables for your VPC - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html):

> **Main route table:** The route table that automatically comes with your VPC. It controls the routing for all subnets that are not explicitly associated with any other route table.

As long as your CloudFormation template associates your custom Route Table with your Subnets, the Main Route Table will not be used. It is the 'default' route table for any subnets that do not have a Route Table specifically assigned.

Given that you say "it's being assigned to all the subnets", it suggests that **you did not create a [AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnetroutetableassociation.html)** that associates a subnet with a route table.

Comment: John is an AWS superman :D